# How to make a bat file so that it executes two different arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I downloaded a [project](https://github.com/OnlyFart/Elib2Ebook) from Git that allows you to save books from various sites
In order for it to work, you need to run cmd in the place where the repository is unzipped. For example, after running cmd and going to the repository location in cmd, to download the book, you need to do the following:

```
Elib2Ebook.exe -u https://author.today/work/212721 -f epub
```

Where "`-u`" is a mandatory argument followed by a link.

"`-f`" is a mandatory argument, followed by the format (for example fb2 or epub)

`Elib2Ebook.exe` - called program

The problem is to automate the process a little bit so that you don't have to enter arguments every time. That is , at startup `.bat` file I just need to enter the argument twice, that is, just insert the link and just specify the format.

I tried to implement it through `%*`, after `call cmd`, but I don't have enough knowledge to really do it, because the problem is that all the arguments need to be entered in one line, separated by the indication "`-u`" (URL) and "`-f`" (format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p "url=What URL https://"
set /p "type=Format : "
lib2Ebook.exe -u https://%url% -f %type%
```

Save as `whatever.bat`

Then run `whatever`

Respond to the first prompt with `author.today/work/212721`
and to the second with `epub`

Done!

[untried]

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Is it possible to make it so that the link can be inserted with the https:// certificate without removing it to the console?

Comment: I'm sorry - I have no idea what you mean. Please exemplify the desired procedure.

Comment: That's it, I figured it out, just inattentively looked at the last line at one point. Thank you very much!